# How do I import the subset of a database into a visual studio 2013 project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to upgrade a Visual Studio 2008 database project to a visual studio 2013 database project.

I've been getting an error like

`[dbo].[trigger_name] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[table_name]`

From what I've read [here](http://programming4.us/database/21550.aspx), it seems to say that you can import a subset of a database somehow:

> SQL Server Database projects are meant to mirror fully the databases
>   to which their contents will be deployed. Although you can create
>   projects that contain just a subset of a database—for example, the
>   assets for a SQL CLR assembly—SSDT will block you as soon as any T-SQL
>   in the project references an object in the database that is not also
>   in your project.

Since I only need 10 tables for my script to run, how do I create these tables in my project, so that I no longer encounter the aforementioned error?

Or, is there a way to link to a database on a server and allow my triggers to verify the object against the actual database schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new db project then right click on it and choose Import database. In 
the Import wizard you will choose which table you want to be imported.
Once you have it imported then go to your actual database project and add database reference which will point to the newly created project.

Second method is to add those 10 tables to your existing project. Right click on the project name and choose Schema Compare. Set your project as a target and Sql Server database as a source, click Compare, choose your tables and click Update target.

You can't add a reference to sql server directly.

Comment: Thanks scar80, your solution worked perfectly!  Just as a follow up, do you know why you are now required to import the database into database projects (as in 2008 it seems you could directly reference the db)?

Comment: Sorry, I use it only since version 2012